# Parsing an HTML document using JavaScript (Node)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to parse an HTML document, but I literally have no idea where to start.

Lets say I have, `<div><p>Hello world</p></div>`

Is there a way to parse this, so I get something like

```
{ name: div,
  children: p
}
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser? You could start by googling "node html parser". BTW, if this is node, please tag it as such.

Comment: @torazaburo - A lot of the html parsers I've found are either broken or not what I need, which is why I decided to do this myself. I also think it'll be good practice for me

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations You should tell us how they were broken, and not what you needed.  Otherwise, writing your own will take about 616 pages of explanation, assuming you are familiar with the material:  https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html

Comment: Hmm, in that case this is "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't have been that hard to find through google 
Here's the link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-json

> htmlToJson.parse(html, filter, [callback]) -> promise
>   The parse() method takes a string of HTML, and a filter, and responds with the filtered data. This supports both callbacks and promises.

```
  var promise = htmlToJson.parse('<div>content</div>', {
  'text': function ($doc) {
    return $doc.find('div').text();
  }
}, function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});

promise.done(function (result) {
  //Works as well 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Cheerio to parse html content to JSON. Try this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping)

[Help Link](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)